# Anddroidmainfeast.xml is not valid

Tags: android, cordova

Why this is happening:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"     package="com.catbolt.qrcode">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true"     android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application android:debuggable="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Qr Code">
        <activity android:configChanges="locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="QR decode" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget id="io.cordova.helloCordova" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
    <name>aa</name>
    <description>xx
</description>
    <author email="support@aa.com" href="http://aa.com">aa
</author>
    <access origin="*" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.AccelListener" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.FileUtils" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.Capture" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.CompassListener" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.NetworkManager" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.ContactManager" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.Device" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.BatteryListener" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.GeoBroker" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.globalization.Globalization" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.InAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Vibration">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.vibration.Vibration" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.Notification" />
    </feature>    
</widget>
```

Comment: Go Downvotes! you can reach -10 !! :)

Comment: please describe your problem better, what you get, you just put two part codes for use and we don't know how we could help you.

Comment: at least put ur LogCat or Log Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android:name` of an `activity` in the manifest should be a Java class name of your activity, not a string like `QR decode`.